# Query from a million records - Linq4j

Tags: java, google-app-engine, linq4j

I just finished testing Linq4j with GAE and with my persistent map:

```
@Test
public void testLinq4j() {
    Map<Long, String> map = Humongous.getMap("Users", LongParser.getInstance());

    map.put(1L, "user1");
    map.put(2L, "user2");

    assertNotNull(map.get(1L));
    assertNotNull(map.get(2L));

    final List<Grouping<Object, Map.Entry<Long, String>>> result =
              new ArrayList<Grouping<Object, Map.Entry<Long, String>>>();

    Linq4j.asEnumerable(map.entrySet())
        .where(new Predicate1<Map.Entry<Long,String>>() {
            @Override
            public boolean apply(Map.Entry<Long, String> v1) {
                if (v1.getKey().equals(2L)){ // filter only those with ID == 2
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        })
        .groupBy(
                new Function1<Map.Entry<Long, String>, Object>() {
                    public Object apply(Map.Entry<Long, String> entry) {
                        return entry.getValue();
                    }
                })
                .into(result);

    assertEquals(2, map.size());
    assertEquals(1, result.size());
}
```

**Question would be:**

- How does  Linq4j internally work with the `map.entrySet()` or with its method `asEnumerable`? In my case `map.entrySet()` ultimately boils down into a Datastore `PreparedQuery` with a safe iterator to all the records in the datastore that matches the query--in the case of the persistent map, it matches every record of a specific `kind`; which could be really big. If my map, like above for "Users" contains like a million records, then this query would be very slow iterating each `Map.Entry`?
- Does `linq4j` call `toList()` when it finds a `Collection<E>?  I ask this because calling this methods copied all the Datastore keys into`a java.util.List` which may cause HeapOverFlowError...